# AngularJS $location.path same url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am wanting to reload the page manually, using

```
 $location.path('/account');
```

correctly moves to a different page however I want to use

```
 $location.path('/account/messages');
```

while on /account/messages to reload the page however it does nothing. What is the correct code for reloading?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: What do you use for routing? ngRoute? ui-router?

Comment: ngroute e.g. $routeProvider.when()

Comment: See the first documented method in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is unclear, if you want a page refresh (like hitting F5), one solution is the @Rabi answer.

But if you just want to reload things under `ng-view`, re-initialized the current route controller, you could use:

```
$route.reload();
```

Also see: [$route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should never refresh an entire page in AngualrJS . 
If you need to do so, you are not using AngularJS correctly . To update a page, all that you need to so is to update the model and the page will be updated accordingly .

The $location service does not provide access to refreshing the entire page. 
If you need to refresh the entire page, you need to use the $window.location object.

```
$window.location.href = "/path/page";
```

Answer (score 2):

By default when using an angular location service, it does not reload or make an ajax call for the same url, it is as per their documentation, if you still want to reload the same url using $location service then try this simple trick.

```
$location.path('/urs_whatever_url/'+Math.random());
```

after changing url code by above line, then also change url in $routeProvider or $stateProvider like 
`url:/'urs_whatever_url/:id'` here `:id` is the dummy variable which now force angular to change the path.